# javascript font size not working

Tags: javascript, fonts, coding-style

why this don´t work:

```
function rp_insertTable() {
 FM_log(3,"rp_insertTable() called");
 var farmTable = dom.cn("table");
 var ftableBody = dom.cn("tbody");
 var i;
 var maximize = GM_getValue("Maximize_" + suffixGlobal, 0);
 farmTable.className = "FMtbg";
 farmTable.id = "farmMachineTable";
 farmTable.setAttribute('cellpadding', 2);
 farmTable.setAttribute('cellspacing', 1);
 farmTable.style.marginBotton = "12px";
 farmTable.style.font = "bold 12px arial,serif";
```

the font does change in format, but the font size is not working, I can put 100px and it deosn´t change anything, why is that?

Comment: document.getElementById('IdeDis').style.fontSize = "14px"; fontSize syntax is only correct.  Please check re again.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try doing:

`farmTable.style.fontSize = "12px";` ?

Comment: doesn´t work also. no font size change. I had already tried it that way also

Answer (score -1):

Accordingly XHTML.com your syntax is off:

Edit, more descriptive: You missed the font-style property in the list, you only had font-weight.

http://xhtml.com/en/css/reference/font/

Also, font is a shorthand, if you just want to set one indeed use the fontSize property.

It probably changes because your font is now no longer well-formed CSS and it sets it back to default.

Comment: The font-style property is optional, as are most of the others.